# Secure Swagger Endpoint With Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger, api-gateway, springdoc

I have been stuck with securing my swagger endpoint with the new spring security 6 for my gateway microservice, i have checked out so many solutions but none are working, i intend to secure the following endpoints : "/webjars/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui/**" and "/swagger-ui.html"; I want to save the userdetails to access these endpoints in spring in memory storage, but unfortunately, it keeps giving me this auto generated password in my logs to use, i have tried using the exclude property of the @SpringBootApplication annotation, but still not working, the following are my codes, please assist in any way, thanks

gateway pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

My SecurityConfig Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/api/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/webjars/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html")
                .authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user1")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

My ApiGatewayApplication Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use something like:

```
return httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .pathMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("/webjars/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").authenticated())
                .httpBasic()
                .build();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the response, but it is not still working, now even worse, it generates a security password, when i try to use it, it doesnt go through and i get 'Encoded password does not look like BCrypt'